# Python pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: password refused

Tags: python, pexpect, pxssh

The following credentials are correct.

```
wolf@linux:~$ sshpass -p bandit0 ssh bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
This is a OverTheWire game server.
```

However it didn't work with Python pexpect.pxssh

```
>>> from pexpect import pxssh
>>> s = pxssh.pxssh()
>>> hostname = 'bandit.labs.overthewire.org'
>>> username = 'bandit0'
>>> password = 'bandit0'
>>> port = '2220'
>>> s.login(hostname, username, password, port)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 402, in login
    raise ExceptionPxssh('password refused')
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: password refused
>>>
```

Comment: I suspect that your given positional arguments in the `login` method is causing the problem. According to the [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh.login) of the method, try `s.login(hostname, username, password, port=port)` instead and see of that works better.

Comment: Thanks @HampusLarsson, it works!. Go ahead and answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error stems from the positional arguments that you're giving the method [`pexpect.pxssh.pxssh.login`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh.login).

According to the documentation, the first four positional arguments of the method is:

```
server, username=None, password='', terminal_type='ansi'
```

So when you're calling `s.login(hostname, username, password, port)` you're setting the `terminal_type` to the port-number.

If you change the last argument into a keyword-argument instead, the port will be set correctly:

```
s.login(hostname, username, password, port=port)
```